# Need help rewriting Python expression into a function

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe formatted like this in pandas.

```
School ID      Column 1       Column 2     Column 3
School 1                      8100         8200  
School 2       9999 
School 3                      9300         9500 
School 4                      7700         7800 
School 5       8999
....
```

I want to be able to enter a value, and if the value is between the numbers in Column 2 and 3, I'd like to return the associated School ID. Right now I have this code:

```
number = (num)
df.loc[(number >= df['Column 2']) & (number <= df['Column 3'])]
```

But I'd like to rewrite it as a function that could also find numbers that are a direct hit in Column 1, so if I entered '8999' the School ID 'School 5' would be returned.

So my desired output would be like this

```
def Find(num):
    return (companyID)
```

or

```
Input Number: 8110


School ID      Column 2    Column 3
School 2       8100        8200
```

or

```
Input Number: 8999

School ID     Column 1
School 5      8999
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
def find(num) :
  d1=df.loc[df['Column 2']==num]
  if len(d1)>0 :
    return d1[['School ID','Column 2']]
  else :
    return df.loc[(num>= df['Column 2']) & (num<= df['Column 3'])][['School ID','Column 2','Column 3']]
```